# Separate io input/output in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

My question is really short. Sometimes we have to separate i/o from a machine for example case of remote file system ? Why we do that ?

Comment: What, are you talking about.

Comment: Separating input output operations from local machines. For example the use of nfs as backend of too web servers.

Comment: Why do you thing the use of NFS for web servers is to separate I/O?

Comment: First reason we shared filesystem. But we isolate io too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes we have to separate i/o from a machine for example case of
>   remote file system ? Why we do that ?

There are a gazillion reasons for this, but those reasons can usually be classified into the following categories:

- increased performance
- increased reliability
- increased availability
- shared filesystems
- physical limitations (e.g not enough space/power/etc. in this server rack for a 64-bay drive enclosure)
- administrative separation (server group has one section of the datacenter, storage group has another section)
- advanced storage functions (things a SAN would provide like snapshotting, replication, etc.)
- etc.